# CSS: Will a nonsense value for the 'display' property cause problems?

Tags: html, css, content-management-system

I am using a CMS that allows data place holders with braces, like so:

```
Name: {First_Name} <br> 
Email: {Email} <br> 
Phone: {Phone} <br>
```

However it doesn't give me any way to do conditional output, like I can't hide the Phone line if the phone field is blank.

The CMS doesn't allow javascript or server side code.  I came up with this trick:

```
Name: {First_Name} <br> 
Email: {Email} <br>
<div style="display:none{Phone}">Phone: {Phone} <br></div>
```

If the person has no phone number, the div ends up display:none, but if they do, the div ends up with a nonsense value for display, and the whole div shows up.

It works in IE8, IE9, FF14, Chrome

Any reason I shouldn't do this?

Comment: Smart solution!

Comment: Why are you using this CMS if it's so restrictive? Also, how are you able to add `<div style="display:none">` but not able to add `<script type="text/javascript">`?

Comment: The CMS strips <script> blocks.  And I didn't ask "Should I use this CMS?", I asked if there was a problem with the resulting HTML, but thank you for your concern.

Comment: Does your CMS quote everything approppriately? Like `style="display:none{" style="display:block}"`

Comment: It does.  {Phone} is replaced with the phone number.  The resulting html comes out as <div style="display:none777-333-2222"> OR <div style="display:none">

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that's absolutely fine; a value that's not understood by the browser, in CSS, doesn't result in an error, it simply ignores that value and displays the element with its default setting for that property.

> [For] illegal values. User agents must ignore a declaration with an illegal value. For example:
>
> ```
> img { float: left }       /* correct CSS 2.1 */
> img { float: left here }  /* "here" is not a value of 'float' */
> img { background: "red" } /* keywords cannot be quoted */
> img { border-width: 3 }   /* a unit must be specified for length values */
> ```
>
> A CSS 2.1 parser would honor the first rule and ignore the rest, as if the style sheet had been:
>
> ```
> img { float: left }
> img { }
> img { }
> img { }
> ```

Citation: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#parsing-errors

Comment: @BoltClock, the bad `display` property will just be ignored, and a `<div>` uses `display: block` by default.

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. I'm not thinking straight tonight.

Comment: It won't since it will make `display:none514354yourphone;` in one word (I know you may had understood that by your last message but it's for the other that read it!)

Comment: @BoltClock, no problem =) (deleting earlier comment.)

Comment: @Zeta: thanks for trying to help, but the reason for using 'unknown properties' was to quote from the W3, from the link in the 'citation.' =)

Comment: @DavidThomas: The rules concerning *invalid values* are stated at the very same source, even in the very list entry. And after all we're talking about invalid rules, not unknown properties ([list entry](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#illegalvalues)).

Comment: Ah? I guess I must've skipped directly over that part; my apologies, you were absolutely right. I'll edit that back in =)